# bit stuffing example

Tags: networking, data-link-layer, bitstuffing

I'm going over an example that reads

> Bit Stuffing. Suppose the following bit string is received by the data link layer from the network layer: 01110111101111101111110.
>   What is the resulting string after bit stuffing? Bold each bit that has been added.

Answer:

```
0111011110111110011111010
               ^      ^
```

How is this answer reached? My understanding is that bit stuffing works by inserting a certain sequence of bits (known as a flag value) at the beginning and end of a frame. What I don't get is:

1. We aren't told the flag value!
2. We aren't told how big a frame is, so how do we know where to put the flag?

**Aditional Information:** I think this network is Ethernet.

**Aditional Information 2:** The bit flag is `01111110`

Honestly I think I understand but isn't the answer incomplete because they didn't add the flag 01111110 to the end or beginging? They just took care of when that pattern of bits appeared in the message.

Other example: [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=L3Leb1RcwJAC&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=ethernet%20framing%20bit%20stuffing&source=bl&ots=2_HJ8CHv4g&sig=9fWqMpwCbX5vHEhhnND30s9SHvs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6ExtUKfEEOrrigKyzoDgCg&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=ethernet%20framing%20bit%20stuffing&f=false) they do it too.

Comment: Bit stuffing is a general concept. You're right that there isn't enough information in what you posted to know what particular bit-stuffing algorithm is being used. This is probably given in the context. What protocol is being discussed?

Comment: @Gilles that it's Ethernet? I kid you not this is all the information I was given.

Comment: @Celeritas Ethernet was a rather vital part of information, the ethernet specification contains full specifications on how bit stuffing is supposed to be done.

Comment: What happens if a delimiter is in the middle of the string. Would you remove it to turn it into the original string as I thought delimiters from the start and end are only removed. (New Question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider: `0111011110111110*0111110*10`

After it finds a `0` and then five consecutive `1` bits it stuffs with a `0`.  This assumes `0` bit stuffing which is common.

Answer (score 12):

For framing in the network in the data link layer, there are some approaches that the bit-oriented is one of them.

It should be a way to know the start and the end of a frame which is transmitting on the link in the receiver side, so there are some format for framing like HDLC. You can see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control).

In the many types of frame formats there are begging sequence (shows the start of frame) and ending sequence (shows the end of frame) and the body of frame which is the data.
The problem that might be occur is the appearance of the ending sequence in the body which may make discern of frame end incorrect.

For preventing from this problem, the sender of frame stuff some bit on the body for disarranging the pattern of ending sequence, this technique known as *bit stuffing*.

Look at this example:

bit sequence: 110101111101011111101011111110 (without bit stuffing)

bit sequence: 1101011111**0**01011111**0**101011111**0**110 (with bit stuffing)

after 5 consecutive 1-bits, a 0-bit is stuffed.

stuffed bits are marked bold.

Comment: bit stuffing used in bit stream connection!

Answer (score 2):

Bit Stuffing:

Input Stream:        `0110111111100111110111111111100000`
Stuffed Stream:     `01101111101100111110011111011111000000`
Unstuffed Stream: `0110111111100111110111111111100000`

Comment: should the newly stuffed 0 be considered further for detecting the sequence 011111 ?  According to your example it seems so, from the last stuffing.  Can you direct to some sources for validating this info pls

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough information in the question to answer it fully for "any" protocol, but Ethernet for example bit-stuffs frame content with a 0-bit after 5 consecutive 1-bits, which seems to be the case here.

As for the rest of your question about the framing, a hint is to look at what is supposed to be passed from the data link layer to the network layer. Is it a pre-framed bit of data or just the frame's content you're looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have to perform bit stuffing , you will always be given the starting and ending marker FLAG bit value
The easiest trick is to remove the last two bits of the flag and note down the new bit series , whenever you get the same series in your data , you have to stuff one bit there .
For eg - 
Given data is 011111011110
Here my FLAG is 0111110  So my my new FLAG will be 01111
I will stuff a bit whenever I get (01111) in my data series ,
So , the data after stuffing will be -
01111(0)101111(0)0 
Brackets imply stuffing here .